# Pull up resistor is broken?

Tags: gpio

As far as I understand, after activating internal pull up resistor like this:

```
GPIO.setup(pin, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
```

GPIO.input(pin) should give me 1. However, I get 0 for pins 38 and 40 (BOARD). Does it mean that pull up resistors are burned on these pins? I hace RPi 3 B+.
Thanks.

Comment: how are you checking the input? Can you post some piece of your code?

Comment: Is there nothing attached to these pins for the test? Otherwise, the actual value read depends on that. Pins 38 and 40 are commonly used for the SPI bus, if the corresponding overlay is active, these might be set to the alternative mode.

Comment: Nothing is connected to the pins, the whole code is: 

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(40, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
print (GPIO.input(40))

The last string returns 0.
In case the code runs faster than pull up resistor is activated, i put time.sleep(1) before print, but I still get 0.